# Error with running the Mocha test cases using chai-http for node services

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I was trying to get a basic hang of writing the test cases using mocha and chai-http ,I had written the test case as below

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

const should = chai.should;
const expect = chai.expect;
const server = "http://127.0.0.1:3000"

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Create Login and Register', () => {
    it('should login using credentials', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/register')
            .send()
            .then((res: any) => {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                done();
            }).catch((err: any) => { done(err) })
    })

})
```

and the service that i'm trying to test is as below

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/register', function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        'state': true,
        'msg': 'Register endpoint',
        'data': {
            'username': 'Swarup',
            'email': 'abc@gmail.com',
            'password': 'P@1234',
            'fullName': 'Swarup Default'
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('started') })

module.exports = app;
```

but when i run the test case i get an error as given below

```
1 failing

  1) Create Login and Register
       should login using credentials:
     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
```

what is that i'm missing or doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not start the HTTP server. You should start the HTTP server in the `before` hook and teardown it in the `after` hook.

Besides, you can have your module **NOT** execute the code in the conditional block at requiring by using `require.main === module` condition. Because we will `require('./app')` in our test file, we don't want to start the HTTP server at requiring.

E.g.

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/register', function (req, res) {
  res.json({
    state: true,
    msg: 'Register endpoint',
    data: {
      username: 'Swarup',
      email: 'abc@gmail.com',
      password: 'P@1234',
      fullName: 'Swarup Default',
    },
  });
});

if (require.main === module) {
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('started');
  });
}

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let app = require('./app');

const expect = chai.expect;
const endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000';
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Create Login and Register', () => {
  let server;
  before(() => {
    server = app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('started for testing');
    });
  });
  after(() => {
    server.close();
  });
  it('should login using credentials', (done) => {
    chai
      .request(endpoint)
      .get('/register')
      .send()
      .then((res) => {
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        done();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        done(err);
      });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  Create Login and Register
started for testing
    ✓ should login using credentials


  1 passing (18ms)
```